# Pass ListView and ArrayAdpater to another class

Tags: java, android, class, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to implement this library https://github.com/ShirwaM/Simplistic-RSS.

The library does as described but I don't like how to handles the feed output. Basically inside a private class in the main activity it directly calls the ListView and ArrayAdapter. That means if I want two ListViews showing two feeds I have to duplicate the whole private class. What I want to do is make it accept a ArrayAdapater and ListView being passed to it so I can spin that class off and then just call it twice passing the relevant feed URL and ListView for output.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private ListView mList;
    private ListView lList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSecond;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rss_layout);

        lList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listTwo);
        mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOne);

        adapterSecond = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.basic_list_item);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.basic_list_item);
        new GetRssFeed().execute("http://feeds.arstechnica.com/arstechnica/index");
        new GetRssFeedSecond().execute("http://feeds.skynews.com/feeds/rss/home.xml");
    }

    private class GetRssFeed extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            try
            {
                RssReader rssReader = new RssReader(params[0]);
                Integer i = 0;
                for (RssItem item : rssReader.getItems())
                {
                    adapter.add(item.getTitle());
                    i++;
                    if(i == 7)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.v("Error Parsing Data", e + "");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    private class GetRssFeedSecond extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            try
            {
                RssReader rssReader = new RssReader(params[0]);
                Integer i = 0;
                for (RssItem item : rssReader.getItems()) {
                    adapter.add(item.getTitle());
                    i++;
                    if (i == 7) {
                        break;
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.v("Error Parsing Data", e + "");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            adapterSecond.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lList.setAdapter(adapterSecond);
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see because `GetRssFeed` is hardcoded with the Adapter and ListView, as per the Simplistic-RSS example code, I need to create two `GetRssFeed` classes to generate two different ListViews. I want to make it so I have one `GetRssFeed` that I can just call with the relevant Adapter and ListView being passed to it.

Comment: You could use an interface callback in the AsyncTask when the data is returned to pass back to the Activity. Holding onto Views in an AsyncTask has drawbacks

Comment: @MikeM. How do you set the Adapter on ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside GetRssFeed Class, add a constructor which accepts 2 parameters, url and listview, if you want to change the adapter then add 3 parameters, like below.

```
public GetRssFeed(String feedUrl, ListView listView) {
   this.feedUrl = feedUrl;
   this.listView = listView;

}
```

Define these 2 variables inside GetRssFeed class as instance variables and use them.

then, from the onCreate, you call like below,

```
new GetRssFeed("http://feeds.arstechnica.com/arstechnica/index", listView).execute();
```

Your single AsyncTask will look like this,

```
 private class GetRssFeed extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
    ListView listView;
    String url;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    public GetRssFeed(String url, ListView listView, ArrayAdapter adapter) {
        this.listView = listView;
        this.url = url;
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try
        {

            Log.d("tag", "nayana url "+url);
            RssReader rssReader = new RssReader(params[0]);
            Integer i = 0;
            for (RssItem item : rssReader.getItems())
            {
                adapter.add(item.getTitle());
                i++;
                if(i == 7)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("Error Parsing Data", e + "");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

From onCreate, you call

```
new GetRssFeed("http://feeds.arstechnica.com/arstechnica/index", lList, ADAPTER).execute();
    new GetRssFeed("http://feeds.skynews.com/feeds/rss/home.xml", mList, adapterSECOND).execute();
```

Comment: I tried formatting it like that but because it's a class the extends ASyncTask it doesn't like format. It's gives an error saying `Class or interface expected`

Comment: sorry, i have tried and its working fine.. i will edit my answer wait

Comment: @JamesKrawczyk, adding constructor in AsyncTask is working fine. Please check my edited answer

Comment: I've implemented this and it works so far as the class, however strangely the for loop no longer iterates for the length of `rssReader.getItems()`. I added a test variable to confirm the length of `.getItems()` and it has 20 items but it exits after running `adapter.add()` once.

Comment: Nevermind it was caused by setting the ListView to the Adapter in the MainActivity as recommend in another comment.